# Ignore spaces in data using VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
    |                      A                 |      B               |     C 
----|----------------------------------------|----------------------|-----------
1   | All Countries     ="All Countries"     |    Search Citeria:   |   Germany       
2   |   Europe          ="   "&"Europe"      |    Result:           |   Germany
3   |     Germany       ="     "&"Germany"   |                      |
4   |     Spain         ="     "&"Spain"     |                      |
5   |     France        ="     "&"France"    |                      |
6   |   Asia            ="   "&"Asia"        |                      |
7   |     China         ="     "&"China"     |                      |
8   |     Japan         ="     "&"Japan"     |                      |
9   |                                        |                      |
10  |                                        |                      |
```

---

In `Column A` in the table I have listed different countries using the formulas that I displayed on the right side. 
As you can see these formulas contain spaces `="   "&` to make the list looking more structured.

---

Now, in `Cell C1` I want to enter a country as a `Search-Criteria` for a `VLOOKUP` in `Cell C2`.

`=VLOOKUP($C1,$A$1:$A$8,1,FALSE)`

As a result I get `#NA` which is probably caused by the spaces I use.

Do you have any idea how I can modify the `VLOOKUP` so it ignores the spaces?

---

**NOTE:** I know I could solve the issue by increasing the `indentlevel` instead of using the `=" "&` logic. 
However, for other purposes I need to go with the `=" "&` instead of the `indentlevel`.

Comment: What is you goal? Why `VLOOKUP` on a single column? Do you simply want to know if "Germany" exists? Or do you want to know its located in "Europe"?

Comment: Simply know if Germany exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is simply to check if "Germany" exists, you could use wildcards:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A2:A8,"* "&C1),C1,"Not found")
```

I still used a space in the criteria simply to avoid `C1` being part of a larger string.

Btw, you can also implement wildcards in your `VLOOKUP`:

```
=VLOOKUP("* "&C1,A2:A8,1,FALSE)
```